# Convert data rows to 1 object

Tags: laravel, collections

Reading Laravel 6 rows like

```
 {"filter_options":[
   {"id":5,"key":"category_id","value":"2","created_at":"2020-02-10 18:23:48"},
   {"id":4,"key":"only_with_images","value":"1","created_at":"2020-02-10 18:23:48"}
  ]
 }
```

I need to convert data in 1 object, like

```
{ 
   category_id : 2,
   only_with_images :"1"
}
```

I know how that could be implemented with a common circle, but are there some collection mapping methods for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if your data is a collection or not, but let's assume this is the data

```php
$array = ['filter_options' => [
    ['id' => 5, 'key' => 'category_id', 'value' => 2, 'created_at' => '2020-02-10 18:23:48'],
    ['id' => 4, 'key' => 'only_with_images', 'value' => 1, 'created_at' => '2020-02-10 18:23:48'],
   ]];
```

you only need to do this

```php
    //after php 7.4
    return collect($array['filter_options'])->flatMap(fn ($item) => [$item['key'] => $item['value']]);
    //before php 7.4
    return collect($array['filter_options'])->flatMap(function ($item) {
        return [$item['key'] => $item['value']];
    });
```

**Note**: obviously this is array syntax to access the properties(`$item['key']`), if your data soruce is from laravel eloquent, you may not need `collect()` helper method and you need to use the object way to access the properties like `$item->key`.